# Python package naming and importing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a package called foo. It's organized as follows:

```
package_dir/foo/foo.py
package_dir/foo/utils.py
package_dir/foo/other.py
package_dir/foo/__init__.py
```

I probably should have named foo.py something else but this library has grown and evolved over time and now supports other stuff and is used all over now. The package is bundled and stored on our internal pipy server so that when installed, I end up with /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foo.

What is the best way to import from this package?

Currently I do this:

```
import foo
```

I then end up doing this in client code:

```
foo.foo.myfunction()
```

There are way to many classes and functions being used to use this approach:

```
from foo import blah, blah, blah
```

This gets kind of klunky. Is this a pythonic approach to packages? Is there a better way to do this?

Thx for any help.

*** update ***

So I've done this but it's not finding my function(s):

```
from __init__.py:

import foo
import utils
import other
```

I then import like this:

```
import foo
```

Then in my code I have tried:

```
foo.myfunc()
```

And also:

```
myfunc()
```

Both complain:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'myfunc'
```

Comment: `import foo as something_else`?

Answer (score 6):

You have some options:

```
from foo import foo
foo.myfunction()
```

Or

```
from foo import foo as something
something.myfunction()
```

Or

```
import foo.foo as something
something.myfunction()
```

Or you can "promote" some APIs so they're published from the top-level.  Import them in `foo/__init__.py` and then you can use them from the package object.  For example, your new `foo/__init__.py` could be:

```
from .foo import myfunction
```

Notice the explicit relative import syntax to avoid ambiguity between the top-level foo package and the nested foo package.

Then you can write:

```
import foo
foo.myfunction()
```

and so on.

Comment: Sweet I'll play with promoting them in __init__.py, that seems that the best option for my stuff.

Comment: @BenH There are examples of this in the stdlib that may be worth looking at. (Not that it's hard to figure out _how_ to do it, but for examples of when to do it, and which names to "promote".) I don't remember which modules off the top of my head, but you can get to the source for the stdlib by going to most modules' documentation and clicking the "source" link near the top and explore from there.

Comment: I can't seem to get this approach working, see my update above. Thx

Comment: added example `__init__.py`